# how to hide icon image from textbox if textbox is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to hide clear icon from textbox if  the length inside the text box is  less then 1.

I tried below code but its not helping me. It does not hide the inner icon if the length of input field is leas then 1.

Example demo is  [click here](http://jsbin.com/exizep)

I tried the below code to hide it.

```
 var myLength = $("#keywords").val().length; 
    if(myLength==0)
      {
        $("span").hide();// i tried to hide it but its not hiding
      }
```

My full code is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <title>SO question 2803532</title>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        var myLength = $("#keywords").val().length; 
                        if(myLength==0)
                        {
                           $("span").hide();// i tried to hide it but its not hiding
                        } 
                        //show the innser clearable icon if users type  any alphabets
                        $("input").keyup(function()
                        {
                            var textbox = $("#keywords").val().length;
                        if(textbox>=1)
                               $("span").hide();// i tried to hide it but its not hiding
                        });


                        $('input.deletable').wrap('<span class="deleteicon" />').after($('<span/>').click(function() {
                            $(this).prev('input').val('').focus();
                        }));
                    });
                 </script>
                <style>
                    span.deleteicon {
                        position: relative;
                    }
                    span.deleteicon span {
                        position: absolute;
                        display: block;
                        top: 5px;
                        right: 0px;
                        width: 16px;
                        height: 16px;
                        background: url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=4') 0 -690px;
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }
                    span.deleteicon input {
                        padding-right: 16px;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <input type="text" class="deletable"  id="keywords">
            </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update you js with this :
here is the fiddle 
`OLD updated one` : http://jsfiddle.net/3VxEH/8/

Todays updated fiddle 7th march ( IST ) : http://jsfiddle.net/3VxEH/20/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $('input.deletable').wrap('<span class="deleteicon" />').after($('<div style="display:none"/>').click(function() {
                        $(this).prev('input').val('').focus();
                    }));
                     //  $(".deleteicon").find("div").hide(); 

                  var myLength = $("#keywords").val().length; 
                //  alert(myLength);
  if (myLength > 0) {
      $(".deleteicon").find("div").show(); 
 }

                    //show the innser clearable icon if users type  any alphabets
                    $("input").bind('ready keyup',function()

                    {
                        var textbox = $("#keywords").val().length;
                    if(textbox>=1)
                    //alert(textbox);
                           $(".deleteicon").find("div").show();// i tried to hide it but its not hiding
                            else {
                                $(".deleteicon").find("div").hide();
                                }
                    });



                });
```

Comment: yours code is not working as i explained in my question. The clear icon should hide if the textbox is empty or there is only single alphabet. Please see my question once more

Comment: small problem, if i am clearing my text from the textbox with small clear icon. Then the clear button should hide because there is not any alphabets in the textbox

Comment: can you please check updated fiddle..its working like that only..if no text then no clear icon

Comment: Your answer is incomplete. i have still a problem. When page loads say that textbox is having few text on it. Then the my clear icon should appear in the textbox. But currently icon is not appering why?. To check this keep          `<input type="text" class="deletable"  id="keywords" value="hello">` instead of the previous one, and save & load the page  in Fiddle

Comment: here is the updated fiddle then..i was not aware that you could have default value as well.. MY BAD..

Comment: again new doubt i clear the loaded text from my textbox with clear button. But still i am seeing the clear btn. It should not show because there is not text inside the textbox

Comment: This i am trying for search. intially when page load textbox will be empty so no point of having clear btn. But if users enter any text then clear btn should appear. and when he hits search button then the search page will load by also having the text type for searching , with the clear btn.

Comment: ookk then try this one now... http://jsfiddle.net/3VxEH/22/ .. i given to my tester as well now he signoff this lol..cheeerss

Comment: Thanks. What do mean by `i given to my tester as well now he signoff this`

Comment: i mean i give the fiddle to tester for to check any bug in this code..anywys i hope your need is fullfill now ?

Comment: yeah man thanks. i tested in static html page its working fine.  Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you use class **`deleteicon`** to hide, use..

```
$('.deleteicon').hide();
```

in your code do the thing,in `.after()` give class name for span there..

```
 $('input.deletable').wrap('<span class="deleteicon" />').after($('<span class="deleteme"/>').click(function()(){

});
```

then use this class **deleteme** to hide or display none..

Comment: i added but its not working. It is not hiding. if i know the exact name/id of the clear icon , then i can easily do. But i tried i am unable to get that. Please modify your answer and help me